# Issue with Javascript < operator returning false when condition is definitely true

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements, operator-keyword

I am having an issue with javascript, which I am using as part of a search results page, hopefully someone can help. I have a function that checks to see that the variable 'currentAmount' is less than the variable 'total'. If currentAmount is less than total, then do something, otherwise do nothing.

```
    var currentAmount = document.getElementById('currentAmountHidField').value;
    var total = '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.ResultCount))';
    var tempScrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();

    function loadMore() {
        alert("current amount" + currentAmount);
        alert("total" + total);
        var listView = $("#propertyList").data("kendoListView");

        if (currentAmount < total) {
            alert("function is being run");
            currentAmount = +currentAmount + 12;
            document.getElementById('currentAmountHidField').value = currentAmount;
            if (currentAmount >= total) {
                $('#loadMoreButton').hide();
            }
        }
        else {
            alert("function is not being run");
        }

        listView.dataSource.pageSize(currentAmount);
        listView.refresh();
        tempScrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    }
```

In the above, currentAmount will always initially be 12. For the most part, this works completely fine but for one instance of the search, where the total = 108, the javascript is processing the else clause of the function. i.e. the alert that says "function is not being run". I can't figure out why.

Note that there are alerts there for testing. It will pop up "currentAmount12" then "total108" then "function is not being run". That doesn't make any sense? I've even tried immediately doing something else with the 2 numbers (e.g subtract 12 from 108) just to check those are being processed as numbers, which they are. And like I say, this is working for every other combination of numbers I've been able to test.

It's like javascript, for one search criteria alone, is reading 12 as more than 108. Interestingly, when I hardcore the value as 12 inside the first line of the loadMore function, it will run as accordingly but obviously that's no good.

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated. Why would javascript think 12 is greater than 108?

Thanks

Comment: *"Issue with Javascript < operator returning false when condition is definitely true"* Step 1: Let go of the belief that the condition is true. It isn't. If it were, the operator would be returning `true`, not `false`. [`select` isn't broken](https://pragprog.com/the-pragmatic-programmer/extracts/tips).

Comment: Log your variables and their type just before the test: `console.log(typeof total, total);`. You'll understand why the result isn't what you think it should be (note that a string isn't a number).

Comment: Make sure you are comparing Numbers, not strings. You can do this on many ways, for instance: `var total = Number('@Html.raw...');`

Comment: You are sure that the comparison is numbers, and not strings? For the heck of it, wrap what you think the are numbers, in a "parseInt (theNumber)". One of the most common reason this happens is what you think is getting compared as numbers are actually getting compared as strings (or one is a number and one is a string).

Comment: You're almost certainly comparing *strings*, not numbers. Instead of fumbling around in the dark with an `alert` torch, *turn on the lights* using the powerful debugger built into your browser. :-) Amongst other things, it will show you both the value *and* type of what you're comparing.

Comment: replace all `alert()` with `console.log()`. You'll see something like `"108"` and `"12"` which indicates you'r comparing strings

Comment: Awesome, thanks guys. Sorted it out now. I was confused that it works in literally every other search that I could possible try, and javascript wasn't giving me any problems doing subtraction calculations with the "strings". I would have thought if the type was string, calculations just wouldn't be possible, but almost all worked.
Thanks very much everyone. Can I give you all the green tick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`currentAmount` and `total` are both strings, so they're being compared lexicographically, not numerically. `'12'` is greater than `'108'`.

Use `parseInt()` to convert the input value to a number, and leave out the quotes around `total` so it will be a number.

```
var currentAmount = parseInt(document.getElementById('currentAmountHidField').value, 10);
var total = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.ResultCount));
```

You obviously knew this was an issue when you wrote:

```
currentAmount = +currentAmount + 12;
```

since the `+` before `currentAmount` is for converting it to a number (so you get addition insteadof concatenation). I guess you didn't know that it also affects comparisons.

Comment: You're spot on Barmar. I just assumed they were being handled as numbers as I've had no issues with it's operation at all until 12 was up against 109. I see now it would also have broken for 100 -> 119 but those never came up in test. Bad testing, cheers for the help!

Answer (score 1):

All values that you get from Form controls are strings, and so that is what your `currentAmount` contains. Then suddenly it should make sense that e.g. "12" < "5", because a "1" is less than a "5".

Solution: use [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) or [`parseFloat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) to get actual numbers in your variables, and not strings-that-resemble-numbers-but-arent.

Answer (score 0):

kindly parse your String variables to your desired types: parseFloat/ parseInt

```
function loadMore() {

currentAmount = parseInt(currentAmount);
total = parseInt(currentAmount);
...


}
```